# I have this error after updating to android studio Giraffe: cannot find implementation RecipeDataBase_Impl does not exist

Tags: kotlin, android-room, code-injection, dagger, arch

AndroidRuntime          com.solution             E  FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.solution, PID: 11392
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.solution/com.solution.view.MainActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: cannot find implementation for com.solution.data.RecipeDataBase. RecipeDataBase_Impl does not exist
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3488)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3635)
at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83)
at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2175)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:237)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7860)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1075)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: cannot find implementation for com.solution.data.RecipeDataBase. RecipeDataBase_Impl does not exist
at androidx.room.Room.getGeneratedImplementation(Room.java:94)
at androidx.room.RoomDatabase$Builder.build(RoomDatabase.java:952)
at com.solution.di.DataBaseModule.getDatabase(DataBaseModule.kt:19)
at com.solution.di.DataBaseModule_GetDatabaseFactory.proxyGetDatabase(DataBaseModule_GetDatabaseFactory.java:33)
at com.solution.di.DataBaseModule_GetDatabaseFactory.get(DataBaseModule_GetDatabaseFactory.java:23)
at com.solution.di.DataBaseModule_GetDatabaseFactory.get(DataBaseModule_GetDatabaseFactory.java:10)
at dagger.internal.DoubleCheck.get(DoubleCheck.java:47)
at com.solution.di.component.DaggerMyApplicationComponent$MainActivitySubcomponentImpl.getViewModelFactory(DaggerMyApplicationComponent.java:267)
at com.solution.di.component.DaggerMyApplicationComponent$MainActivitySubcomponentImpl.injectMainActivity(DaggerMyApplicationComponent.java:280)
at com.solution.di.component.DaggerMyApplicationComponent$MainActivitySubcomponentImpl.inject(DaggerMyApplicationComponent.java:272)
at com.solution.di.component.DaggerMyApplicationComponent$MainActivitySubcomponentImpl.inject(DaggerMyApplicationComponent.java:261)
at dagger.android.DispatchingAndroidInjector.maybeInject(DispatchingAndroidInjector.java:113)
at dagger.android.DispatchingAndroidInjector.inject(DispatchingAndroidInjector.java:134)
at dagger.android.AndroidInjection.inject(AndroidInjection.java:59)
at dagger.android.support.DaggerAppCompatActivity.onCreate(DaggerAppCompatActivity.java:43)
at com.solution.view.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:74)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7955)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7944)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1307)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3463)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3635)
at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83)
at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2175)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:237)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7860)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1075)

I have tried many questions related to this but still have this error

Comment: This is my build.gradle file